# Task#apply versus Task#delay

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given the following `scala.concurrent.Task` instance created via `Task#delay`:

```
val t = 
   Task.delay { println(Thread.currentThread); Thread.sleep(5000); 42 }
```

I wrote a method that will run `t` asynchronously.

```
def f = t.runAsync { 
      case \/-(x) => println(x)
      case -\/(e) => println(e.getMessage) 
}
```

Running it shows that `f` evaluates entirely, i.e. waits 5 seconds, and then evaluates again. In other words, the second `f` appears to wait until the first `f` had completed

```
scala> {f; f; }
Thread[run-main-0,5,run-main-group-0]
42
Thread[run-main-0,5,run-main-group-0]
42
```

Then, I re-wrote `t` using `Task#apply`:

```
val u = 
  Task { println(Thread.currentThread); Thread.sleep(5000); 42 }
```

Again, I defined a method that executes `u` with `runAsync`:

```
def g = u.runAsync { 
     case \/-(x) => println(x)
     case -\/(e) => println(e.getMessage) 
}
```

Finally, I ran two `g`'s.

```
scala> {g; g}
Thread[pool-3-thread-2,5,run-main-group-0]
Thread[pool-3-thread-3,5,run-main-group-0]

scala> 42
42
```

However, in the above result, the `g`'s, more or less, ran at the same time.

I had expected that `{f; f; }` would've run asynchronously, i.e. in the same way as `g`. But, it seems to me that calling `f` resulted in a block.

**EDIT**

[Task](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.0/scalaz_2.11-7.1.0-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.concurrent.Task)'s docs note on `runAsync`:

> Any pure, non-asynchronous computation at the head of this Future will be forced in the calling thread.

Since `t`'s body is non-asynchronous, I suppose that the above comment explains why it blocked, i.e. "forced in the calling thread."

When is the right time to use `Task#delay` versus `Task#apply`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of `Task.delay` as a fancy version of something like `() => Try[A]`. It suspends evaluation of the computation, but doesn't have anything to say about what thread that evaluation is eventually going to run on, etc. (which means it's just going to run on the current thread).

This is often exactly what you want. Consider a definition like this:

```
val currentTime: Task[Long] = Task.xxx(System.currentTimeMillis)
```

We can't use `now` because that would evaluate the time immediately (and only once, on definition). We could use `apply`, but forcing an asynchronous boundary for this computation is wasteful and unnecessary—we actually *want* it to run in the current thread, just not right now. This is exactly what `delay` provides.

In general when you're modeling your computations, if something is always going to be computationally expensive, you might want to consider `Task.apply`, which means the evaluation will always happen on a thread determined by the current implicit `ExecutorService`. This may make usage a little cleaner, at the expense of flexibility—you're baking something you know about the runtime characteristics of the evaluation of the computation into its definition.

The nice thing about using `delay` to define your asynchronous computations is that you can always force an asynchronous boundary by wrapping your `Task` with `Task.fork`, which gets you essentially the same thing you'd have if you'd defined the computation with `Task.apply`. It's not possible to go in the other direction—if you use `Task.apply`, the implicit strategy is going to determine where the computation is evaluated and that's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks, Travis! Would `Task#apply` be appropriate when wrapping a legacy, blocking JDBC call? Let's assume, for purposes of this question's scope, that re-writing the legacy DB call is not an option.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yeah, that'd definitely be an example of an API where you want to decide what thread the computation will run on.